# Webpack: How to tame non npm compliant js library

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

I have js libraries that initialize themselves like the following:

```
(function(root) {
   ......
   ......
})(this)
```

when built with webpack, I get something like

```
function(module, exports) {
   (function(root) {

    })(this)
}
```

The "this" is not window as the libraries would assume. Is there a neat way to tame this type of library to work with webpack? My last resort would be hackly replace the this with window using postloader or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, we call these 'broken modules' because like you said they simply execute in the global context there are a few different methods to shim these kind of modules.

[Here is a list of different options](https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html) (as the solution cam vary per library). I like using the `ProvidePlugin` or using alias and externals.

Comment: Oh wow,  Thanks. That's exactly what I need. I guess it works with import syntax too.

Comment: It does, it just varies on the variety of the library!